# Code to detect "control-c" or failure in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, solaris

I wrote a bash script to automate a very long process.
It works good.

However, if the user should control-c or rerun due to a ssh disconnect I find that there is a remnant of the previous execution still running if I: ps -ef|grep myprogram.

I believe the problem is in this snippet of code in which I background each step so I can show the user a spinning progress bar:

```
<snippet begin>
function progress {
 SPIN='-\|/'
 # Run the base 64 code in the background
 echo $THECOMMAND | base64 -d|bash &
 pid=$! # Process Id of the previous running command
 i=0
 while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null
  do
   i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
   # Print the spinning icon so the user knows the command is running
   printf "\r$COMMAND:${SPIN:$i:1}"
   sleep .2
  done
 printf "\r"
}
<snippet end>
```

Question: What code can I add to my script that will detect a failure or control-c and kill the background process?

Additional info:
I run the script from a wrapper and I run this in a screen session.

```
myprogram.sh $1 > >(tee -a /var/tmp/myprogram_install$DATE.log) 2> >(tee -a /var/tmp/myprogram_install$DATE.log >&
```

Comment: Look up the `trap` command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
quit=n
trap 'quit=y' INT

progress() {
 SPIN='-\|/'
 # Run the base 64 code in the background
 echo $THECOMMAND | base64 -d|bash &
 pid=$! # Process Id of the previous running command
 i=0
 while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null
  do
   if [ x"$quit" = xy ]; then
    kill $pid
    break
   fi
   i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
   # Print the spinning icon so the user knows the command is running
   printf "\r$COMMAND:${SPIN:$i:1}"
   sleep .2
  done
 printf "\r"
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Pleading ignorance here.  Can you help me understand how this works?  I assume INT is an interrupt??  How does `x"$quit" = xy` get evaluated?

Comment: No. `INT` is the `SIGINT` signal, and `[ x"$quit" = xy ]` is the test `$quit == y`.  When you press Ctrl-C a `SIGINT` signal is delivered to your script, and `quit` is set to `y` because of `trap`.  You can then test for the value of `quit` in your function.